# Include index from object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

Please somebody guide me in the right way

i have this object

```
myObject = {"Timer13":{"Arm":0,"Mode":0},"Timer14":{"Arm":1,"Mode":1}}
```

And i need get this array

```
[{"timer":"Timer13", "Arm":0,"Mode":0},{"timer":"Timer14","Arm":1,"Mode":1}]
```

I tried several ways,  i dont get it;

it is my incomplete result using map

```
var result  = Object.keys(myObject).map((i) => myObject[i]);
```

and i get

```
 [{"Arm":0,"Mode":0},{"Arm":1,"Mode":1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try appending a key and add the rest of the elements to the object before returning from the map.

```js
var myObject = {"Timer13":{"Arm":0,"Mode":0},"Timer14":{"Arm":1,"Mode":1}}

var result = Object.keys(myObject).map(elem => {
    return {timer: elem, ...myObject[elem]}
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can return an object from an arrow function by surrounding it in parens to avoid the `return` statement: `Object.keys(myObject).map(elem => ({timer: elem, ...myObject[elem]}))`

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries and map new objects by assigning the parts.

```js
var object = { Timer13: { Arm: 0, Mode: 0 }, Timer14: { Arm: 1, Mode: 1 } },
    array = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([timer, values]) => Object.assign({ timer }, values));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)  to achieve that playing  with Current Value `(curr)` an
Accumulator `(all)` also destructing your array can be helpful for a cleaner code. `[timer,obj]`  timer : `curr[0]` and the obj is `curr[1]`

```js
obj = {
  "Timer13": {
    "Arm": 0,
    "Mode": 0
  },
  "Timer14": {
    "Arm": 1,
    "Mode": 1
  }
}

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((all, [timer, obj]) => {
  all.push({
    timer,
    ...obj
  })
  return all;
}, [])


console.log(res)
```

Comment: i don't understand why i am getting -1 :) the output is correct  i think